# Defining a table template for a document

Tags: tables, macros, formatting

I am trying to create a document which automatically updates certain values according to an output from a python code. From this python code, it produces a latex table, which looks pretty basic. However, I have to integrate this table with the document template, so that it matches the rest of the pre-written tables in the document.

The document template for tables are provided by for eg:

```
\begin{table}[H] \centering
    \caption{Nominal Skirt Annulus}
    \label{tab:nomskirtannulus}
    \begin{tabular}  {p{2cm}p{3cm}}
        \rowcolor{blue}{\textcolor{white}{Skirt Thickness} } & {\textcolor{white}{Nominal Annulus} } \\ 
        
    10 & 11 \\
        
        
        \hline          
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}
```

In this template, the number of columns and rows are variable.

The python generated latex table looks like:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{bleh}
\label{tab:bleh}
\begin{tabular}{ppp}
\toprule
             Tolerance & Bottom &  Lowest Can Weld \\
\midrule
       Annulus nominal &        0.098000 &                 0.098000 \\
     MP flange ovality &        0.001000 &                 0.001000 \\
     
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This table should be formatted according to the template (with row colour, text colour etc) automatically. Is there a way to do this in Latex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safe version which I will strongly recommend is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ mytbl }{ O{} m +b }{%
  \begin{tblr}{%
      colspec={#2},%
      row{1}={%
        bg={blue},%
        fg={white},%
        font={\bfseries}% 
      },%
    }%
    #3%
  \end{tblr}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytbl}{clr}
  \toprule
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  \midrule
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  \bottomrule
\end{mytbl}
\end{document}
```

This will require you to rename all the generated `tabular` environments to `mytbl`. Maybe there will be some way to ask Python to generate `mytbl` instead of `tabular` directly. This will keep all the other `tabular`s untouched and safe. If you use any package which uses `tabular` for some purpose, that tabular will also stay safe.

If you are *absolutely* sure that you (and packages you use) are only going to require `tabular`s of this specific type, then the following might be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tabular}{ O{} m +b }{%
  \begin{tblr}{%
      colspec={#2},%
      row{1}={%
        bg={blue},%
        fg={white},%
        font={\bfseries}%
      },%
    }%
    #3%
  \end{tblr}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{clr}
  \toprule
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  \midrule
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  abcd&efgh&ijkl\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Both will generate:

[image: 1]

---

#### Edits:

1. Add `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}` command for supporting `booktabs` commands with `tblr`.
2. Add `booktabs`-rules to the table-code and change the output-screenshot.

Comment: If you require more things in the table, feel free to ask, I will try to add them.

Comment: Yeah, the template is fixed; so the second code worked. By any chance, is it possible to to remove the midrule from all the tables by including an input at \RenewDocumentEnvironment? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad that this worked for you :) Regarding the next question, if you want to remove all the `\midrule`s at one go; you can simply issue the following command in the preamble **after loading `booktabs`**: `\def\midrule{}`. Basically you just forget what `\midrule` means ;-)